# How to change number of item per page in taxonomy page?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms, 7, paging

I have multiple content types. I want to change number of item per page in teaser mode and  it is different for every content type.

In `admin/config/system/site-information` we can change number of item for all content types. But I want to change number of items for each content type.

What do I do? Please help.

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Admin > Structure > Views`. Enable the `Taxonomy Term` View :

[image]

In views configuration change the pager settings as you want.

Comment: I eneabled this view but in taxonomy page don't show any thing while in preview of this view show node of defined term id.i dont know that dont show any thing in any taxonomy page?

Comment: Can I see the screenshot of configuration you change after enabling the view?

Comment: please describe config of view

Comment: Well you have added a filter in filter criteria. It seems it has some tid filter. I think because of that it is not displaying list. Try to see after removing the filter.

Comment: no when i remove this filter but yet dont show any thing.when i enabeld this view with default config dont show any things.!!!

Comment: Well, It seems translation issue or something like that. Can't say without checking it.

Comment: I want to display different number item per page for every content type.thus i need add a filter that specified content type.please help

Comment: No, filter is not required in that case. I don't think if it is possible without some custom coding.

Comment: please describe how i do number of item per page in any content type that different for any content type?

Comment: in this view i can number of item for all content type as same.bu i want to be different. and unforunately dont display any things in taxonomy page???